# Which cheap microcontroller with Wi-Fi to choose for IoT endpoint devices?

Tags: wifi, microcontroller, internet-of-things

I want to gather data from multiple sensors, make simple operations on them (like store last samples in a buffer, calculate moving average, etc.) and send them to the Internet of Things cloud using WiFi. Which MCU should I use for this purpose?

**Constraints:**

- Cost: cheaper than $25
- Size: smaller than the [Arduino Uno](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno)
- Storage: more than 1KB non-volatile memory
- Interfaces: I2C, serial, WiFi
- Computing power: supports TCP/IP stack, ideally with TLS
- Security: some kind of encryption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is [**Particle** (f.k.a. **Spark**) **Photon**](https://www.particle.io/) - STM32F205 ARM Cortex M3 microcontroller with Broadcom BCM43362 Wi-Fi module, 1MB flash, 128KB RAM for $19.

Second option is [**WiFiMCU**](http://www.wifimcu.com/) - STM32F411CE ARM Cortex M4 microcontroller with Broadcom  Wi-Fi module, 2MB SPI flash, 512KB on-chip flash, 128KB RAM for $10.

Another option is a much cheaper **[NodeMCU](http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html)** - ESP8266 microcontroller with 64 KB SRAM, 96KB DRAM, 4MB flash for $4.

The last option is [**SparkFun ESP8266 Thing**](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13231) - also based on ESP8266 with On-board LiPo battery charger for $16.

All of MCUs support full TCP/IP stack and partial SSL.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that mbed TLS (PolarSSL) works with BSD sockets which requires running an RTOS (ST has official resources for FreeRTOS).